# Sqlalchemy AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'dispatch'

Tags: python, postgresql, session, sqlalchemy, fastapi

**Hello!**

**When session commit, infrequently happens this error.**

**Interestingly, this error can occur in any part of the project and rarely comes out intermittently.**

We use fastapi structure with sqlalchemy

Session create:

```
from sqlalchemy import create_engine
from sqlalchemy.orm import scoped_session, sessionmaker

from app.core.config import settings

engine = create_engine(
    settings.SQLALCHEMY_DATABASE_URI,
    pool_size=10,  # default in SQLAlchemy
    max_overflow=5,  # default in SQLAlchemy
    connect_args={"application_name": settings.PROJECT_NAME},
    echo=settings.POSTGRES_ECHO,
)

SessionLocal = scoped_session(sessionmaker(bind=engine))
```

```
from typing import Generator, List
from app.db.session import SessionLoca


def get_db() -> Generator:
    db = SessionLocal()
    try:
        yield db
    finally:
        db.close()
```

```
@router.put("/")
def endpoint(
        data: schemas.UpdateSchemas,
        db: Session = Depends(deps.get_db),
) -> Any:
```

**Error**

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/app/app/api/api_v1/endpoints/otp.py", line 24, in check_otp
    customer = crud.customer.create(
  File "/app/app/crud/base.py", line 56, in create
    db.commit()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.10/site-packages/sqlalchemy/orm/session.py", line 1451, in commit
    self._transaction.commit(_to_root=self.future)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.10/site-packages/sqlalchemy/orm/session.py", line 843, in commit
    self.close()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.10/site-packages/sqlalchemy/orm/session.py", line 928, in close
    self.session.dispatch.after_transaction_end(self.session, self)
AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'dispatch'
```

Comment: Evidently `self.session` is `None`.  But it's impossible to know why without a [mre].

Comment: Added more info about session creation

Comment: Same issue. I have no idea why this happens intermittently